# send multiple email to different persons based on email id and a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a below table and I am using it to send email using `sp_send_dbmail`

```
DATA  ENTITY  Email    
------------------    
1     ABC     a@mail.com;b@mail.com
2     ABC     a@mail.com
```

currently I am sending both rows to both email ID using `"sp_send_dbmail"`. But I want to change in such a way that first and second row goes to a@mail.com and first row to b@mail.com separately. Is there any possible way to send as I mentioned.

Comment: This database design is several **broken** - you should *never* has multiple values in a single column - it violates even the **first normal form** of database design. Fix this first

Comment: I am not sure what you mention by broken. as you see my column has multiple values but separated by ";"

Comment: Basic principle: one column should always contain at most **one** value (or nothing), but never **multiple values** - separated or not....

Comment: Check out [basic info about first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), find yourself a `Beginner's introduction to database design` book somewhere and **read it** and learn (and embrace!) at least the three normal forms of relational database design

Comment: Please post your current code that is causing the undesired behavior.   I don't see how this can not be a simple matter of programming.

Comment: HI all I have used BEGIN and call each ids individually